# Question about Matsumura Theorem 23.4

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have one question about the proof.
[image]

I'm not sure why $I$ is of the form $(A/m)^t$.

My thought: Here $A$ is a Noetherian local ring of dimension zero, so it's Artinian. So $m$ is nilpotent, $m^t=0$ for some $t>0$. Therefore $I=m^{t-1}$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathfrak mI=0$, so $I$ is an $A/\mathfrak m$-vector space (finitely generated). That's all.