# Validity about Matsumura Theorem 23.4

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is related question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145734/question-about-matsumura-theorem-23-4). Suppose $(A,\mathfrak{m}),(B,\mathfrak{n})$ are zero dimensional Noetherian local rings (thus Cohen-Macaulay), and $f: A \to B$ be a local homomorphism. Then, let $I=(0:\mathfrak{m})_{A}$. In the proof of theorem 23.4, author claimed that
$$(0:\mathfrak{m}B)_{B} = IB.$$
My question is, why does the equation hold? Definitely, $(0:\mathfrak{m}B)_{B} \supset IB$, but I cannot show the other inclusion. <strike>Moreover, I think I have a counter-example. For example, let $A=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{2})$ and $B=\mathbb{C}[Y]/(Y^{3})$ and $f:A \to B$ by sending $X$ to $Y^{2}$. Then $I=\mathfrak{m}=(X)$, $(0:Y^{2})_{B}=(Y)=\mathfrak{n} \neq IB = (Y^{2})$. How the author conclude the above equality?</strike>

EDIT: As @user26857 says, $B$ should be flat over $A$. Thus I just delete my example which is not flat.

Comment: B is assumed flat over A.

Comment: @user26857 Oh I definitely miss that condition... However, it is still unclear to me how flatness gives the other inclusion. Could you give me a little bit more hint?

Comment: Matsumura, Theorem 7.4.

Comment: @user26857 Yeah, that's the basic thing I need to remember.. Thank you very much!!!